# What word best describes talking sweetly but in a sarcastic manner?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm writing a character who is cynical and cruel, but the way he speaks is very sarcastically sweet to further emphasize how jaded he is by the nature of the world and men, but I can't find a word that describes this type of "fake sweetness". He very often says stuff like "My my, if you're so bothered by my antics, what are you going to do about it?" and just sounds so pleasant and well-versed, but his tone is dripping with sarcasm, but sarcasm has connotations of bitterness or scorn and he's not being scornful, he's genuinely curious what they come up with in the hopes of entertaining him.

Comment: *saccharine* has a figurative meaning of 'sickly sweetness' which also carries connotations on insincerity. BTW, what is it that he is well versed *in*?

Comment: This seems like a contradiction: the character is cynical and cruel, speaks sweetly (which will make him sound scornful/condescending), and you don't want this to convey bitterness or scorn? I think that can only be conveyed through characterisation.

Comment: @Spagirl he's a jack-of-all-trades and has been alive for a very long time, so he knows a lot about most anything, so naturally is always yearning for something new and interesting to crop up that he hasn't already experienced.

Comment: @kasfme he is kind of contradictory by nature, but in this context he's talking with a long-time dear friend that he's not actually trying to scorn, but rather tease with his sickly sweetness.

Comment: @SueBee I don't think that any specific word choice will help you. You'll need to give behavioural clues and write the dynamic between the characters in such a way that it conveys what you wish to convey (eg. the friend not taking offence.)

Comment: @kasfme that's what I figured I might have to do, I just wondered if there was a singular word I couldn't find or was just not thinking of that would help make the context more clear. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @SueBee be aware that 'Jack-of-all-trades' is part of a of phrase which ends 'master of none'. It may not help in conveying that he is accomplished in many fields.

Comment: @Spagirl I hadn't used that phrase specifically in my writing, but that is very good to know. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

I'd go with **saccharine**

> too sweet or sentimental : sweet or sentimental in a way that does not
>   seem sincere or genuine

This derives from early use of saccharine, which was one of the first artificial sweeteners. While the resulting taste was sweet, it also had an overtone which made it fairly easy to realize that it wasn't really sugar.

Comment: This should be marked accepted, it's definitively the one best answer.

Answer (score 0):

The closest single word may be "gibe". It is the translation of the Spanish, "puya" which literally means "tack" or "thorn," but which is also used to describe a carefully crafted comment that appears to be a compliment, but is actually meant to be deflating to the one for whom it is intended (the effect of a carefully-placed tack).

For example"
"That new top is perfect for you. It's remarkable the way it seems to cover those extra pounds."

"Congratulations on the new job! will you be moving out of you parents house soon?"

Answer (score 0):

I'd say **honeyed.** A honeyed voice is sweet and pleasant to listen to but is not sincere. I'm not sure if this is accurate enough - probably only describes the tone - but hopefully it helps. Combine this with "condescending" and I think it'll pass. (Sorry, first time answering a question on here)